# Remove all non-unique characters from a string with RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to remove all non-unique characters from a string with RegEx.

For example, 'hollow' will return 'hw'

I've looked around for a solution, but the best I've found was

```
(.)(?=.*?\1)
```

But that removes duplicates and leaves the final copy untouched.

Comment: I don't think regex is the best option here...

Comment: You may use this regex to match any of the chars that are duplicated, remove that char, and repeat the search until no match.